# Can anyone please explain Polymorphic association in details with an example?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I know that With polymorphic associations, a model can belong to more than one other model, on a single association.
I want to know what is the meaning of a single association.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct about the definition of polymorphic associations. The term "single association" means that we can use a combination of `record type` and `record id` to serve multiple `belongs_to` relationships. I understand that this may sound as vague as the definition itself. So I'll use the example mentioned in the [Rails guide description of polymorphic associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations):

```
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end
```

Here, the `picture` model is a polymorphic one, which has two columns, `imageable_id` and `imageable_type`. It uses these two columns to establish relationships with *any* models, which have a `has_many :pictures, as: :imageable` relation. In the above example, when we add a `Picture` for an `Employee` with id 3, a record is created in the `Picture` model as:

```
#<Picture id: 1, url: "some_url", imageable_type: "Employee", imageable_id: 3....>
```

Note how the imageable_type and imageable_id help us identify which exact record in our system, this picture belongs to. For a `Product` with id 3, the picture would be as follows:

```
#<Picture id: 1, url: "some_url", imageable_type: "Product", imageable_id: 3....>
```

*Without* polymorphic associations, we would have had to add 2 columns, `employee_id` and `product_id` to have `belongs_to` relationships with the models described above. Imagine a scenario where 5-6 models different could have pictures!

**What are the advantages of using polymorphic associations?**

1. They help in having a uniform API for interacting with a shared resource (like pictures, comments etc)
2. Allow easy addition of new models which can share the resource, without adding new columns. This also helps in avoiding multiple unused columns in a record